# Python: Difference between "re.match(pattern)" v/s "re.search('^' + pattern)"

Tags: python, regex

While reading the docs, I found out that the whole difference between `re.match()` and `re.search()` is that `re.match()` starts checking only from the beginning of the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'abcde'
>>> re.match(r'b', a)
>>> re.search(r'b', a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xffe25c98>
>>> re.search(r'^b', a)
>>>
```

**Is there anything I am misunderstanding, or is there no difference at all between `re.search('^' + pattern)` and `re.match(pattern)`?**

Is it a good practice to only use `re.search()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at [Python's `re.search()` vs. `re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) document which clearly mentions about the other difference which is:

> Note however that in [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) mode [`match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) only matches at the beginning of the string, whereas using [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) with a **regular expression beginning with '^' will match at the beginning of each line**.
>
> > `>>> re.match('X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # No match`
> >
> > `>>> re.search('^X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # Match`
> >
> > `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 5), match='X'>`

The first difference (for future readers) being:

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default).
>
> > For example:
> >
> > `>>> re.match("c", "abcdef")    # No match`
> >
> > `>>> re.search("c", "abcdef")   # Match`
> >
> > `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='c'>`
>
> **Regular expressions beginning with '^' can be used with [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to restrict the match at the beginning of the string**:
>
> > `>>> re.match("c", "abcdef")    # No match`
> >
> > `>>> re.search("^c", "abcdef")  # No match`
> >
> > `>>> re.search("^a", "abcdef")  # Match`
> >
> > `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at this from a *code golfing* perspective, I'd say there is some use in keeping the two functions separate.

If you're looking from the beginning of the string, `re.match`, would be preferable to `re.search`, because the former has one character less in its name, thus saving a byte. Furthermore, with `re.search`, you also have to add the start-of-line anchor `^` to signify matching from the start. You don't need to specify this with `re.match` because it is implied, further saving another byte.