# Using regex with list comprehension in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have following code which will store all the csv filename in a list from a specific folder

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import os

files = os.listdir('.')
filename=[filename for filename in files if filename.endswith('.csv')]
```

However, in my folder, I have two types of csv files, one ends with, for example, _20.cvs(or maybe _18.csv,_01.csv), another one ends with _Raw.csv;

However I only need the first type stored in my list. I know regular expression may can help me on that, so I did some google search, and come up with the following code, but it seems doesn't work, can anyone offer a advice?

```
filename = [re.search(r'^\d{2}.csv'),filename).group(0) for filename in files]
```

Comment: BTW, do you have `_20.cvs` or `_20.csv`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove `^` (as it matches the start of string location), add `$` at the end of the pattern (to make sure the match is at the end of the string) and escape the dot (else, `.` matches any char but a line break char).

Note you must check if there is a match before accessing `.group()`:

```
result = [f for f in files if re.search(r'_\d{2}\.csv$', f)]
```

**Details**

- `_` - an underscore
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `csv`  - `csv` text
- `$` - end of string.

See the [***regex demo***](https://regex101.com/r/9LuSLL/2).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/xYAYzo):

```
import re
files = ["gfrt_32_20.csv", "wertf_18.csv", "12_01.csv", "ith_Raw.csv"]
result = [f for f in files if re.search(r'_\d{2}\.csv$', f)] 
print(result)
# => ['gfrt_32_20.csv', 'wertf_18.csv', '12_01.csv']
```

Comment: @Borisu There is no need adding the details about `re.match` and `re.search` difference into my answer as OP problem is not related to it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355460/python-difference-between-re-matchpattern-v-s-re-search-pattern) is a good thread on that.

Answer (score 3):

re.match would not work because it matches at the beginning. Use re.search instead.
But everything else is fine in the previous solution.

```
import os
import re
files = os.listdir('.')
filenames = [f for f in files if re.search(r'(_\d+.csv)', f)]
print(filenames)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `re.match` method:

```
import os
import re
files = os.listdir('.')
filenames = [f for f in files if re.match(r'(_\d+.csv)', f)]
print(filenames)
```

Comment: it gives me empty; the filename is like :Mydate_2018_11_22.csv; but we only care about 22.csv? right?  for this instance, i think match and search are the same?

Comment: @Frank could you provide exmples with full names of files, which you need to collect? Yes, they are same. In this case `re.search` and `re.match` can replace each other.

Comment: [f for f in files if re.search(r'(_\d+.csv)', f)] works; [f for f in files if re.match(r'(_\d+.csv)', f)] doesn't

Comment: Data_100000_11_22.csv

Comment: @Frank for "Data_100000_11_22.csv" i got this regex: `r'^Data_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+).csv$'`

Comment: @Frank could you provide small LIST of full names of files?

Comment: Data_100000_11_22.csv; Data_100000_11_12.csv;Data_100000_11_26.csv

Answer (score 1):

You should put the regex operation in the `if` clause so as to filter out those you don't want.

You should also escape the `.` in the regex, since dots have special meaning in regex (match all non-line terminators).

```
[filename for filename in files if re.search(r'\d{2}\.csv$', filename)]
```

If you want only the matched bit, you can do a simple substring:

```
[filename[-6:] for filename in files if re.search(r'\d{2}\.csv$', filename)]
```